# What's the right way to do counts in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, count

I have a rails app with many following pieces of code:

```
Our active community of <%= Account.find_all_by_admin(false).count %>
```

My question is is this the right way to do counts on views? It seems so "dirty" is there a more railish, way to do counts? I'm thinking named scopes perhaps, but I just want to be sure that these type of things won't have  a greater impact in performance.

Thank You,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would recommend you to avoid direct access to database in my templates because then you're losing a bit of flexibility when it comes to caching.

Try to prepare all the data you need to render in your action instead and then use meaningful instance variables like `@number_of_accounts` or `@accounts.count`.

This will make your views cleaner and easier to debug and also a bit more DRY if you render action in different formats (html, json, etc)

As to how do you get your numbers - it doesn't really matter that much, just move away from find_* methods towards scoping and write readable code

Comment: This was the kind of answer i was looking, for I know how to do it, I just wanted to know the BEST way to do it.

Answer (score 17):

You don't need a name scope to perform a count.

```
Account.where(:admin => false).count
```

But named scopes are an excellent way to make your code more reusable.

Named scopes don't have any noticeable performance impact on your application.

Answer (score 3):

In rails 3 a simple call to count issues a simple count request:

```
Contact.count
```

is resolved as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_id FROM "contacts"
```

a find all by field name will resolve as:

```
Contact.find_all_by_country("Canada")

SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE ("contacts"."country" = 'Canada')
```

I would recommend indexing your admin column for faster lookups and this can be translated into a named scope, but that by itself will only predefine the query, not optimize it.

It is important to note that if you issue

```
Contact.find_all_by_country("Canada").count
```

`count` is a method on the array class and doesn't actually issue a count on the database:

```
Contact.find_all_by_country("Canada").count

SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE ("contacts"."country" = 'Canada')
```

Comment: also take a look at this article: http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/

Answer (score 2):

A named scope shouldn't have an impact on performance

```
scope :not_admin, where(:admin => false)
```

Then you can have `Account.not_admin.count`

Edited per DGM's comment: To check the generated SQL in a console, compare `Account.not_admin.to_sql` with `Account.find_all_by_admin(false).to_sql`

Comment: `Account.not_admin.count.to_sql` is an error, at least in rails 3, since count returns a Fixnum.

Comment: Oops. Couldn't test here, but you must be correct. However, Account.not_admin.to_sql and Account.find_all_by_admin(false).to_sql should be equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query instead of `Account.where(:admin => false).count`

```
Account.select(:id).where(:admin => false).count
```

Just select one column, instead of selecting all. It generates the following query and it is faster than the previous one:

```
SELECT COUNT("accounts"."id") FROM "accounts" where admin = false
```

Answer (score -1):

You should create an `instance variable` in the controller and use it in the view.
This will make you view clear.

```
@accounts_count = Account.where(admin: false).count
```

And use it in the view like `<%= @accounts_count %>

If you want to loop though the results along with the count, you can use the following way:

```
@accounts = Account.where(admin: false)
```

in view, write like below:

```
<%= @accounts.count %>
// For looping account
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
  # do some stuff
<% end %>
```

But the above way will fire 2 queries, 1 for count and other for the loop.

**Correct Approach**

Use `size` instead of `count`. It will fire 1 query but you need to change the order of count in your view like:

```
// For looping account
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
  # do some stuff
<% end %>
<%= @accounts.size %>
```

If you want the same order, then load the user object first like below

```
<%= @accounts.load.size %>
// For looping account
<% @accounts.each do |account| %>
  # do some stuff
<% end %>
```